# Python 3 tkinter Listbox resetting

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

As part of a larger Raspberry-Python3.5 app, I build a tkinter Listbox filled with a simple data list.
Whenever I rebuild the list with new data, the tkinter **adds a new list bellow the old one instead of using the same object, replacing just the data.**
I have tried any option I could imagine (and some odd ones as well...) to get only one list, but for no avail.
How can I delete the old object and / or build a new one and / or just replace the data?.
Here is a short working example:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()  

datalist = 0 ,66 ,42 ,553 ,68

def run():
    listbox = tk.Listbox(root)
    listbox.insert(0,datalist)
    listbox.pack()

stepbutton = tk.Button(root, text = "Step", command = run)
stepbutton.pack()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delete the existing items first if you want to replace them with a new list. You can delete list items using the `.delete()` method. This would delete all the items in the listbox.

```
listbox.delete(0, 'end')
# then insert new list here
```

To do what you're doing, create one listbox, and swap the contents of the listbox in the command `run()`, ie.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()  

# listbox to display data
listbox = tk.Listbox(root)
listbox.pack()

datalist = 0 ,66 ,42 ,553 ,68

def run():
    global listbox
    # clear listbox
    listbox.delete(0, 'end')
    # insert new contents
    listbox.insert(0, datalist)


stepbutton = tk.Button(root, text="Step", command=run)
stepbutton.pack()
```

Comment: This is an obvious reply, which I have tried, but one cannot delete a non-existing object. (I defined the object as global but still the same)
Please run the code and show me how you can delete the object or fill it with new data

Comment: Thanks strava. This made me understand I should have initialized the listbox as global in the constructor to be able to delete it before reloading.

Comment: This also made me understand what to do but the code was not working for me. Maybe because of python 3?